# The effect of withWatermark without aggregation

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I wonder what is the effect of `.withWatermark()` if there is a stream without any aggregation, basically one to one mapping to the output sink? Does date get dropped, or withWarmark time window is ignored in such case?

Thanks for clarification.